# How to use SvnProtocolHandler

Tags: internet-explorer, svn, tortoisesvn

SvnProtocolHandler (http://tortoisesvn.net/svnprotocolhandler.html) allows Internet Explorer to access Subversion repositories using the SVN (svnserve) protocol.  I downloaded the package, which consists of a half dozen DLLs.  However, I can't figure out *HOW* these DLLs are intended to be used with IE.  Suggestions, please?

I'd try to contact the author (Stefan Küng) if I knew how.

The package looks useful -- I just can't get off the launch pad.

Comment: http://tortoisesvn.net/community.html

Comment: Looking at the download page, it comes as an msi installer - does it not install the dll files to the correct place automatically? Or are you wanting to do something other than install it?

Comment: @orbrey I've just tried SvnProtocolHandler on a machine with IE11 and it indeed doesn't work. Don't see anything related on the web about this. It's either the handler doesn't support newer IE versions or some additional witchcraft is required to make it work.

Comment: Thanks @bahrep, was just in the process of testing with IE8 to see if that would work but seems you've got it :)

Comment: @orbrey it was Stefan who actually hepled: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3090669

Answer (score 1):

It appears that if you install 32-bit version of SvnProtocolHandler, then it works without any questions. If you install 64-bit version, then it will work with 64-bit IE only. See the explanation at users@ TortoiseSVN mailing list here: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3090669.